# How to store large queries inside code for ADO.NET project

Tags: c#, ado.net

I am working on a web project for which data access layer is based on ADO.NET (for fastest execution). There are some very large SQL queries in the project which are written inline in C# code. I was wondering if I can move those queries somewhere more elegantly to reduce some mess but am unsure what approach can be used. I know about resource files but those can't be used here as some queries are parameterized.

Language: C#

Comment: I've both used consts in the type (and put them at the bottom of the class definition and separate repository types that were the SQL, parameter handling and minimal result mapping. Litteral strings help but non-trivial amounts of SQL just doesn't fit with C# well (the syntax is too different).

Comment: What do you mean with _some queries are parameterized_? Can you give an example of these parameterized queries and why do you think they cannot be stored in resources?

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to make use of views or stored procedures?

Comment: you may use the same approach as used in https://github.com/nreco/data - this lib has concept of 'app-level' dataviews that are queried as read-only data tables. Also it is possible to pass custom parameters that could be rendered in any place of complex SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are unable or unwilling to use Stored Procedures and prefer to keep the Sql close to the C# code you could extract the Sql and put them in to external files, included in the project as per the images.

**Option 1: Text file copied alongside executable in a sub-folder**

[image: File Copy Always]

And access its contents like this:

```
    private String LoadFileContent()
    {
        String fileName = "Sql\\LoadAllData.sql";

        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            String errorMessage = String.Format("File '{0}' does not exist or access to it is denied", fileName);
            throw new FileNotFoundException(errorMessage, fileName);
        }

        String fileContent = String.Empty;
        using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(fileName))
        {
            fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return fileContent;
    }
```

or

**Option 2: Text file embedded as a resource in the assembly**

[image: File as embedded resource]

And access the file using this method:

```
    private String LoadAssemblyResource()
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        String fileName = "StackOverflowWinForm.SQL.LoadAllData.sql";

        // Handy bit of debug code to list all the resource names in case there
        // is an issue trying to find/load a resource
        String[] resourceNames = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();

        String fileContent = String.Empty;
        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(fileName))
        {
            if (stream == null)
            {
                String errorMessage = String.Format("Resource File '{0}' does not exist", fileName);
                throw new MissingManifestResourceException(errorMessage);
            }

            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                fileContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }

        return fileContent;
    }
```

I would recommend the latter method of an Embedded Resource if you are developing a Web Application or Web Service so you don't have to worry too much about mapping paths, security, and text files on the web server being hacked/altered.

Both of these methods replace the string literals in code and move them to an external file. Once the external file has been loaded, the string can still be manipulated in the same way as before.

I often use both methods depending on the exact circumstances and size of the Sql in question.

Comment: What about parameterized SQL statements in this way? For example SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id = {PARAMETER}

Comment: Whether you do
String sql = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE student_id = {PARAMETER}";
OR
String sql = LoadFileContent();
the resulting content of the variable sql will be the same and therefore you can use String.Format, String.Replace (and all the other functions) in exactly the same way

Answer (score 0):

I recommend putting the queries into SQL Stored Procedures, and using ADODB.Command objects to run them.  You can apply the same principals to code running System.Data.SqlClient queries.

Depending on the complexity of how you are building the query, it might make sense to create multiple queries to replace your inline calls. In particular, if you have a block of code that filters by product OR by store OR by chain (for example), and those are all handled by one block of dynamic C# code to build the command, it would be better to have 3 separate stored procedures in SQL to handle each case than to try to duplicate that dynamic behavior in one procedure.

An added benefit to this approach is that you will probably find better overall performance and index tuning opportunities with the stored procedures due to the way SQL builds query plans.

Some general comments about how SQL manages query plans:

If you build your stored procedure in your database SQL will generate a query plan the very first time each procedure is run, using whatever parameters and flow that call requires to optimize the query.  If you load your queries dynamically - whether with generated dynamic SQL or by loading SQL scripts saved as files - Then SQL runs this analysis every time the call is run.

Generating the query plan every run is a performance hit.  Depending on your database and your query, this hit can be very minor - a few milliseconds on a query that runs once a day - or very major - a second or two for a query that runs thousands or millions of times a day.

Splitting your calls in to 3 separate procedures is a good idea because SQL Server builds the plan on the first run example. If you have a procedure that takes an optional ID value, and returns one row if you pass the value, or all rows if you don't... then depending on which one gets called first, SQL is going to try to either do an index lookup or table scan every time you call it, neither of which is optimal for the other operation.  Splitting this in to two separate calls allows SQL to generate an optimal query plan for each operation.

Another aspect of this is more for logging and analysis.  Many SQL performance tools, including those built in to SQL, are able to look at many calls of the same stored procedure as related, and identify long term performance trends.  Some tools even do a really good job of pinpointing the exact parts of the procedure which run poorly.  If you're using dynamically generated SQL, however, those calls all become a sea of separate events. So your 3 second call made millions of times a day would get lost if you have a long running stored procedure that bubbles up once or twice a day, but if the 3 second call is a stored procedure then you can see that it collectively becomes 90% of your server workload, and a good candidate for refactoring and query tuning.

So, while it feels a little bit like you're violating the DRY principal to generate multiple similar queries as separate stored procedures, you want to adjust your mindset when working with SQL to get the best performance.

Comment: I can't go with the stored procedures approach as the application is multi-tenant application and each customer has its separate database. I want to avoid SP replications as much as possible.

Comment: Randy R, why did you say this: " it would be better to have 3 separate stored procedures in SQL to handle each case than to try to duplicate that behavior". What will be benefits?

Comment: user1451111  - there are two main reasons, both related to how SQL Server runs code.  I'll update my answer to explain...